# babel-plugin-styled-components not work with preset-typescript

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, styled-components

I use Typescript in my project and use Babel7 preset-typescript to transform Ts. And I want to add babel-plugin styled-components to my project, but it does not show component display class name

Another option for typescript styled component tooling is typescript-plugin-styled-components. But it seems to work with webpack typescript loader. Since I use babel7 to transform TS so I dont use TS loader in webpack

Here is my babel config:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "modules": false
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "babel-plugin-styled-components",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "react-hot-loader/babel"
    ],
    "env": {
        "production": {
            "only": ["src"],
            "plugins": [
                "babel-plugin-styled-components",
                "lodash",
                "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
                "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements",
                "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Could you guys show me the way to fix my babel-plugin-styled-components? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution for TS. Try this one: github.com/Igorbek/typescript-plugin-styled-components

[image: screen shot of my code with component name as class]